# Unable to translate message in magento 2

Tags: magento2, translate

I want to translate quantity error message.  [image]

I changed in

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/i18n/fi_FI.csv

```
"We don't have as many ""%1"" as you requested.","Meillä ei ole pyytämääsi määrää tuotetta ""%1"".",module,Magento_CatalogInventory
```

and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fi_FI` command
but it's not working

Comment: before run command of deploy you need to run `setup:upgrade` command. did you try this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was the same msg in the fi_Fi.csv  which contain the translation in English language only. So I just removed that line from the file.

Answer (score 1):

When you do translation you don't need to pass ""%1"".

example :

```
"Get %1 off","obtenez %1 de réduction" - this will be you CSV file
```

in you PHTML file you should have :

```
$discount = $block->getDiscount(); - if your using block
$discount = $viewModel->getDiscount(); - if you are using view model

  <?= __("Get %1 off", $discount) ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following way..

```
"We don't have as many ""%1"" as you requested.","Meillä ei ole pyytämääsi määrää tuotetta ""%1""."
```

i have above code translate in **fr langugage** this work good for me

```
"We don't have as many ""%1"" as you requested.","Nous ne possédons pas suffisament de ""%1"" pour honorer votre demande."
```

**Note:** Clear cache (`php bin/magento cache:clean`) and check your changes.

Comment: I tried, it's not working

Comment: not possible @BhaktiThakkar  i have checked my side working fine and you have search all project any module override this text and csv file available

Comment: I add this line in /app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/i18n/en_US.csv

Comment: https://github.com/bthakkar96/EnglishToFinnish/blob/master/en_US.csv